# Clearcase - Unable to access VOB - ls: reading directory - Permission denied

Tags: centos7, clearcase

```
Clearcase Server Version - 8.0.1.19
OS – Centos - 7.6.1810 (Core)
```

**Problem:** Created new VOB, Mounted the VOB then created dynamic view on server successfully. From VOB root directory ls command shows below error.

```
ls: reading directory .: Permission denied
total 0
```

I have executed below protect commands.

```
cleartool protectvob -f -chown ccadmin -chgrp testvob-grp /vobstg/testvob.vbs
cleartool protect -chown ccadmin -chgrp testvob-grp -chmod 775 -r .


[root@VOB-Server /]# cleartool desc -l vob:/vobstg/testvob
versioned object base "/vobstg/testvob"
  created 2019-11-21T09:01:57+05:30 by ccadmin.testvob-grp@VOB-Server
  "This is test VOB."
  protected by rolemap: "DefaultRolemap"
  effective access for user "root": rmelem,Read
  VOB family feature level: 8
  VOB storage host:pathname "VOB-Server:/vobstg/testvob.vbs"
  VOB storage global pathname "/net/VOB-Server/vobstg/testvob.vbs"
  database schema version: 80
  modification by remote privileged user: allowed
  atomic checkin: disabled
  srfm: disabled
  evil twin detection: disabled
  VOB ownership:
    owner ccadmin
    group testvob-grp
  minimum client feature level: 8
  ACLs feature level: 8
  Attributes:
    FeatureLevel = 8
```

`View owner has rwx (all)` permission.  So in newer version of Clearcase do I need to enable configuration for even root id and VOB-owner ID?

I am using default config spec

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/LATEST
```

Dynamic view created with root account. While describing the VOB tag it shows below error.

```
[root@VOB-Server]# cleartool desc -l /vobstg/testvob
cleartool: Error: No permission to resolve: "/vobstg/testvob".
cleartool: Error: Unable to access "/vobstg/testvob" because either it is unreadable or its containing VOB is not accessible to the current user.
```

Whereas with VOB Owner’s account/ID (`ccadmin`), I can able to describe the VOB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it depends on your config spec (I will assume `element * /main/LATEST`)

Second, your question mentions `root@VOB-Server`: make sure to do the `ls` test as the view owner: `ccadmin.testvob-grp`

Still as the view owner, do a `id -a` to check if the primary group (or one of the secondary groups) is part of the VOB group (VOB, not view, which is correctly protected)

See "[Access control for VOBs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/r_access_vob_vob.htm)" and "[About Additional Groups in the VOB's group list](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21147137)"

> You can use the `cleartool describe` command to display the owner, group, and supplemental group list for a VOB.

```
cleartool descr -l vob:/vobs/vobtag
```

> Whereas with VOB Owner’s account/ID (ccadmin), I can able to describe the VOB.

That is expected: only user with the primary Vob group as part of their group would be able to access the Vob. `root` has not `testvob-grp` in its groups (`id -a`)

Comment: protected by rolemap: "DefaultRolemap" something i need to change?

Comment: @Kishore No, there is no need to change anything: you just should not use root except  for exceptional cases. For describing or using the Vob, stick with the Vob account owner. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Oh sorry for the inconvenience caused. I thought that in root account it work (I have used 10 years back) it was working that time, seems now for security reasons it has been protected. But Thanks a lot.